# Flutter - Import a dart file within the project

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to import auth_user.dart, and for some reason it tells me that:
"**Target of URI doesn't exist**"

Here's my project:
[image]

I tried doing:

```
import 'package:notes_pro/services/auth/auth_user.dart';
```

What am I doing wrong? (I'm sure it's obvious, sorry in advance!)

Comment: You should use the complete path as you wrote that you tried doing. It could be as simple as VSCode not realizing that the file is there. Try closing the folder in VSCode and  opening it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing it with the full path and package name should work.
Otherwise, check if the name in the pubspec.yaml file matches what you are using  in your path ('package:notes_pro/services/auth/auth_user.dart') when doing imports.

Comment: That's it! The name inside pubspec.yaml was different than the project name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just use "auth_user.dart" and it will work. Those imports use simple terminal paths. So if you have any project file within different folders you can use "../second_directory/auth_user.dart"

".." will move up one directory